# Adding items to select does not work in Chrome

Tags: jquery

I have following code that works fine in IE8.  The jquery code add items to a multi-select list. But in Chrome and Safari this is not working - The items are not visible

Note: Though it works in Firefox, it is aligning to the right. And when I select any option item, it gets hidden.

How can we make it working in all four browsers?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/UPR8K/

**CODE**

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("#btnCostPageNumberMagnifingLens").click(function () {

            $("#mtxtCostPageDescription").append('<option value=1>My option</option>');

        });
    });
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">

    .floaterleft
    {
        width:300px;
        height:300px;
        background-color:gray;
        padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;

    }

</style>

<body>
    <div class="floaterleft">
        <div class="headerTextBox">
            <input id="txtCostPageNumber" id="CostPageNumber" name="CostPageNumber" style="width: 240px; padding-right: 15px" type="text" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="Magenifyingbtn, headerMagnifyButton">
            <input type="button" name="btnCostPageNumberMagnifingLens" id="btnCostPageNumberMagnifingLens" class="Magenifyingbtn">
        </div>

        <select id="mtxtCostPageDescription" name="mtxtCostPageDescription" multiple="multiple" style="width: 290px; padding: 10px 152px 0px 154px; float: right"></select>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: the only reason might be all options has the same value

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UuEkA/

Comment: yeah they all have value 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is at select style

```
padding: 10px 152px 0px 154px;
```

This hides the options

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bW7k7/5/) padding removed from style on the element

Answer (score 1):

You are repeating document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
```

Comment: true, but not the issue

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Dipesh, additionally, the  elements are being hidden due to

```
padding: 10px 152px 0px 154px;
```

in the  elements style attribute. Chrome and Firefox are (correctly) applying the padding to the  elements.

Padding will define the space between itself and its **content**, while margin will define the space between itself and its **parent**.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J2wJC/)

Search Google for more information on CSS Box Model: [Google](https://www.google.co.za/search?q=css+box+model)